# DensityPlot is wrong

Tags: plotting, visualization

```
DensityPlot[(
 ArcCot[(2 y)/(1 - 2 x)] + ArcCot[(2 y)/(1 + 2 x)])/1, {x, -10, 
  10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

What it should look like:

[image]

What it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add `Exclusions` to the plot and increase `PlotPoints`:

```
DensityPlot[(ArcCot[(2 y)/(1 - 2 x)] + ArcCot[(2 y)/(1 + 2 x)])/
  1, {x, -10, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 Exclusions -> {x == 1/2 || x == -1/2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is there a way to force mathematica to evaluate the function in a grid? Quite a few times Mathematica has given me a wrong plot because it was trying to be a little too smart for its own good.

Comment: @grdgfgr ListDensityPlot in combination with Table.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to use `ArcTan` instead of `ArcCot` and then you can use the two argument form of `ArcTan`:

```
 DensityPlot[(ArcTan[2 y, 1 - 2 x] + ArcTan[2 y, 1 + 2 x])/
        1, {x, -10, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

This is a "reasonable" plot as-is and identical to @SjoerdCdeVries plot with `PlotPoints->100` ( `Exclusions` not needed )

Answer (score 1):

For completeness: here is a simplified version of the function being plotted by the OP (using an appropriate addition identity):

```
DensityPlot[ArcTan[4 x^2 + 4 y^2 - 1, 4 y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

[image: density plot]